# How to scrape twitter user followers using Beautifulsoup and Requests in python?

Tags: python, session, twitter, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape twitter followers of a celebrity. But I am unable to get the required data. I am unable to login to the twitter using requests. I have tried some code.

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 payload={   "session[username_or_email]":"**********@gmail.com",
"session[password]":"****************",
"authenticity_token":"************",
"ui_metrics":'{"rf":{"a78f48eaa010bb984c59cd3a407b880cb4567ac8a19754298475d1b69af8f825":-40,"ae42c829ba1baf0e72bad0350609e797ad3e34cd4ca71d5d7d996e4f37b0583a":222,"a93a62f3ecdad0b170abe01c18bd28a4e93aa819f1fffa0680f52dafd2bd0c27":-138,"a03b033ba773faf2e2f3e2befad0612296aeb8ffc2cc5b2b35b99f855698f07a":-81},"s":"d9bgNWsxqGpvE1MK7WoIaZDYdF24drlt-5xdktyALQ1mGMpcrwQSoAmrhlE20PQsyUSJRC9Y82EWey-gmkrbH_0s2qInOWRnwto8Fih-VMbwGMr-RfbhXrM3zXDzEJmXV16JPzR4vKaA664j4MTIYgiqBxH5EXhheBjBIFIMzZIMAjyiltBLn27m6ZuCUSuO0o50Kj5X9Npu-3PqVyFUoTEuaFsiZm73XZoDuKhwFnbj65MLrwuGGkjD2mJaTfqAkL1Ecdm7tp84A22GDXH8RYtzTGehoqdUeqaDDq6g2DOU72kGpPBgpmWE-d-5HCEfxFRXO-rircZCwlN9_d53QAAAAWEmNWDl"}',
"scribe_log":"",
"redirect_after_login":"",
"authenticity_token":"**************",
"remember_me":"1"}

res = requests.get("https://twitter.com/login",data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    print(item.text)
```

How to make this code work? Please help me with this. 
**Note:** I dont want to use APIs. Please help me to solve this.

**Update:**
I have modified the payload part and when i execute it, i am getting empty result. When i debug it, debugger is terminating immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Check your networking tab, console or logs for the HTTP response status and and post it.

Even better, walk through your code with your debugger and inspect the response object for a code and/or message.

Post those here for more help.

If you don't want to use the REST API, your challenge will be emulating a browser request from your script. Mind sharing why you don't want to use the REST API?

Good luck.

Update in response to OP comment:

What do you mean by terminating immediately? Set a breakpoint in the first line of your code and step through line by line. What is the response code? 200? 400? 300? Comb through the response object in your debugger for clues. The REST API is documented, and so if you need guidance that would be a great place to start, while maintaining more flexibility than a full on SDK.

Where did you get these request parameters? What makes you think they will produce the desired response?

Comment: Hi! I have changed the code a bit. When I try to run it, i am getting empty result. Please help. I just want to try without using APIs.

Comment: I have done the debugging by putting a break point at payload line. When i start the debug process, it is terminating without giving any response. And I got the parameters from the form data in the network section in the "inspect"